# MySQL create default date column with begining of month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a MySql default date column that shows the begining of the current month.

Many solutions already solve this for the current time stemp such as:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
`date`     DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

How do I do this but rounding it to the first day of the current month?

Comment: You can use an expression as default since 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 8.013 Mysql supports functions as default value, so you can make

> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo (
> id bigint auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
> `date`     DATETIME DEFAULT (now() - interval (day(now())-1) day),
> dt DATETIME DEFAULT  (subdate(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), (day(curdate())-1))),
> test varchar(5)
> )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO foo (`test`) VALUES ('a')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM foo
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date                | dt                  | test
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :---
>  1 | 2022-07-01 16:21:17 | 2022-07-01 16:21:17 | a
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80a22af9666e89b6c97e12631f5837bf)*